# Where does an ActiveRecord extension module should be placed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this module:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
 class << self
  def has_simple_search(*attrs)
   raise 'has_simple_search expects at least one attribute' if attrs.empty?
    instance_eval do # because this is ActiveRecord::Base, the class inherits this
     class_attribute :simple_search_fields
     self.simple_search_fields = attrs.flatten
     def simple_search(search_string)
      return find(:all) if search_string.nil? || search_string.blank?
      attrs = self.simple_search_fields
      like_s = attrs.map{|f| "#{self.table_name}.#{f.to_s} REGEXP ?"}.join(' OR ')
      terms = search_string.split(' ').map{|s| Regexp.escape(s.strip)}
      where(Array.new(attrs.count, terms.join('|')).unshift(like_s))
     end
    end
   end
  end
end
```

https://gist.github.com/Florian95/2478919

I've trying to implement this in my Rails application but I'm unable to find where should I place it.

Also: Is this code reusable for rails 4?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should place it into `config/initializers`.

I really can't tell if it's reusable on Rails 4, try it out.

Comment: Do I need to add something to the models? As long as I understand Model#simple_search(query) should be working after I create the initializer. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. All you need is a file with the exact contents above and it should work. If it doesn't, it probably is not Rails 4 compatible.

Comment: Could the person that downvoted this please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: I've tryed and worked in the initializer. But It's not very reusable.

Comment: Perhaps you should read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down I'm okay with downvoting, but accepting the answer at the same time... it's just weird.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. What's the point on downvoting and marking as correct? I wasn't just pointing that it worked but you were pointing that might not be reusable.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the misunderstanding.